# Visual Studio 2022 C++ standard libraries could not be found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, c-standard-library

I installed the visual studio 2022 community edition with a C++ Desktop development package[Screenshot of Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgKuT.png).
When a new console application is built getting errors C++ standard libraries could not be found. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.[Screenshot of Visual Studio 2022 build errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaQhr.png)

Comment: Those are all IntelliSense errors, and should be taken as an approximation. What happens if you compile the project? (Remove IntelliSense errors from the error list filter.)

Comment: OK, Now i am getting the following error "Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you show us some configuration screens of your project?

Comment: Did repairing Visual Studio work? Please check whether the Windows SDK version in your project configuration is latest.

Answer (score 2):

Start Visual Studio Installer and select "desktop development with C++".

Comment: The package mentioned by you was selected at the time of installation. Code building with errors.

Comment: Try to repair Visual Studio.
Start Visual Studio Installer and select More->repair

Comment: In my case I had to uninstall and reinstall the Windows 10 SDK in the Visual Studio Installer to a different version. This was on a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022, so I'm not sure why it came with the wrong SDK version (or why the other SDK didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

For me VS2022 17.2.6 required both "Desktop development with C++" and "Windows 11 SDK" enabled in the installation details on the right hand side. I had the Windows 10 SDK enabled before but (as the name might suggest) that was insufficient since I am running Windows 11.

In case you do not know where to find those settings:
--> Visual Studio Installer
--> Modify button next to your VS 2022 installation

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, you need to specify the installed  SDK  version in the project's properties -> Windows SDK Version.